# CasperJS can access browser elements on one system, but not another

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I'm having a problem with CasperJS (version 1.1.0-beta3) and PhantomJS (version 1.9.2).  I wrote a script on my work machine and it runs fine.  I want this script to run on another machine (a test machine), though, so I made an SVN repo on a server and mapped a network drive to it from the test machine.  In the repo, I have my script, the contents of the extracted CasperJS zip, and phantomjs.exe.  I also updated the system PATH variable on the test machine.

I mapped the same network drive on my local machine, where it ran fine before.  It still runs fine on there, even from the network drive.  It won't run on the test machine, though.  CasperJS and PhantomJS are working fine, but the script doesn't seem to be able to access the site.  All my captures come back blank, and it can't find the controls.

The site I am trying to access is https://admin.surescripts.net.  Right now, all I'm trying to do is log in.

If I write a whole new test just to try to get out to Google, Casper can get out to the site to screencap it.

I've tried putting in a wait command to check for timing issues, and running it against a different environment of the same website.  No luck.  What could be going wrong?

Here is the cmd output from the test machine:

```
Z:\Automated Entry>casperjs automatedentry.js
CasperError: Errors encountered while filling form: form not found
  Z:/CasperUtils/CasperJS/modules/casper.js:802 in fillForm
  Z:/CasperUtils/CasperJS/modules/casper.js:862 in fillNames
  Z:/Automated Entry/automatedentry.js:51
  Z:/CasperUtils/CasperJS/modules/casper.js:1553 in runStep
  Z:/CasperUtils/CasperJS/modules/casper.js:399 in checkStep
```

Comment: Is the site local or remote? What URL or path are you using to access it?

Comment: The first troubleshooting would be the network level. On linux I would use wget or curl to make sure the URLs can be reached. (A quick search shows there is a "Wget for windows", at least.)

Comment: @DarrenCook - I don't think it's a network issue, since the test machine has an internet connection and I can access the site through a browser.

Comment: What I mean is first confirm it works with wget (or curl or equivalent), i.e. from the commandline. Then if it does (as you predict it will) run it in the most verbose mode to find out what IP it connects, what headers it sends, what headers it received. Post that here, along with the equivalent from casperjs (assign a logging function to `onResourceRequested` and `onResourceReceived`). And play Spot The Difference :-)

Comment: @DarrenCook - I was able to stumble upon the solution based on your suggestions.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran wget and then assigned logging to `onResourceRequested` and `onResourceReceived` like Darren suggested, and I discovered that the problem was PhantomJS:

```
[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail: https://admin.surescripts.net/
```

Turns out PhantomJS was throwing an error because of the page's SSL.  Adding `--ignore-ssl-errors=yes` to the cmd args when I ran it fixed the problem and allowed the script to run.

Why it happens on my test machine and not on my local, I still have no clue.  Meanwhile, if anyone has any suggestions on how to write this flag into my script so that I don't have to type it every time I run the test, that would be welcome.  I've already tried using `pageSettings: { ignoreSslErrors: true }` within Casper's `create` method, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html says there is no ignoreSSLErrors setting. I guess it needs to be given to Phantom at start-up time. Use a windows batch file to save having to type it each time?